# Checking types of slices in golang

Tags: go

I use the reflect package to check the type of my variables. For example if I want to check if var is an integer I do:

```
reflect.TypeOf(var).Kind == reflect.Int
```

How can I check if my variable is an int or float slice?

I can only see Slice as one of the types returned by Kind() but this slice could be of any type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a type is slice,`Elem()` will return the underlying type:

```
func main() {
    foo := []int{1,2,3}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(foo).Elem()) //prints "int"
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(foo).Elem().Kind() == reflect.Int) //true!
}
```

You better check that it's a slice before, of course.